# Jenkins CVS plugin doesn't find changes on Head if location is branch

Tags: jenkins, branch, cvs

First off, I know similar questions exist on Jenkins CVS plugin page but I believe this is somewhat different.

I have a job in Jenkins which is parameterized and gives us the possibility of building a specific branch of the project (for patches etc). Fine so far. But most of our builds are against Head so I mark the option "Use Head If Not Found". The job correctly checks out Head and perform the build.

My problem is that the "Poll SCM" build trigger never detects changes on Head nor do we get any changelog in the builds in Jenkins.

So the questions are. Do I expect the wrong behavior? Do I use it wrong?

Thx, Christian